# How to make instabot post a photo that I have saved as a variable?

Tags: python, bots, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to make the bot go through all the files in the folder and post them.

```
This is what I have been trying

import os
from os import listdir
import instabot
bot = Bot()
directory = 'directory name'

bot.login(username = "username", password = "password")

def poster():
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        Bot.upload_photo(filename, caption="hi")
        sleep(600)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in poster
TypeError: Bot.upload_photo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'photo'
>>>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please add also all packages that you use.

Comment: Are you sure that `filename` can only be an image file? And have you tried calling the function with: `Bot.upload_photo(photo=filename, caption="hi")`? I looked at the actual code and it seems to be not important, but worth a try